# Detectar cambios en una ventana

Tags: vb.net

Se pueden detectar cambios en los gráficos de una ventana?

Pongo unas imágenes para explicarme mejor:

Esta imagen es una zona de un programa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si esa zona cambia, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debería detectarlo de alguna forma.

No necesito detectar el mensaje en sí, simplemente con detectar que hay un cambio  es suficiente.

Esto sería para utilizar en diferentes pcs con diferentes resoluciones. Es decir que el tamaño de la ventana cambia.

Comment: A que te refieres con "Ventana"? a una zona de la pantalla comprendida en unas coordenadas? a una ventana de una aplicación? A otra cosa?

Comment: A una zona de la pantalla en unas coordenadas.
Pero debería estar en segundo plano la aplicación.
Quiero detectar cambios en una GUI externa (no programada por mí)

Comment: Lo mas probable es que si, si pudieras interceptar los mensajes a la placa de video.. .ningun programa te va a informar cambios en la ui asi como asi...

Comment: Como poder, sin duda se puede. El problema es que tu pregunta, me parece, es demasiado amplia. Por un lado, debes resolver la forma de monitorear la pantalla o un sector de esta cada x cantidad de segundos o menos para realizar capturas que luego deberías comparar, y lo siguiente es que algoritmo usar para detectar diferencias entre dos capturas determinadas.

Comment: Exactamente eso es lo que estoy tratando de hacer :)

Comment: Tengo que estar de acuerdo con @PatricioMoracho. Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia, lo que intentas conseguir no es trivial. Creo que, como alternativa a lo que te comentaba Patricio, habría posibilidad tal vez de hacerlo monitoreando los mensajes de la aplicación que tratas de "espiar". Pero como digo, no es algo sencillo. Trata de implementar algo y si te encuentras con algun problema concreto, vuelve a preguntar y trataremos de ayudarte :)

Comment: He intentado haciendo reverse y no encuentro la posición de memoria de lo que sería la lista de mensajes donde aparecerían textos (como en el ejemplo), he encontrado otros valores que podrían ser de interés pero no para mi propósito y son todos tipo double y 4 byte (por si ayuda). Probaré con Ultimap 1 de Cheat Engine a ver si saco la llamada a la función pero nunca lo he utilizado... Tampoco sé ahora mismo como detectar llamadas a funciones en vb.net, sé inyectar el proceso y leer direcciones de memoria pero "cazar funciones al vuelo" eso ya no.. alguna idea? muchas gracias!! :)